# How to further partition/split an already partitioned dask dataframe

Tags: dataframe, cluster-computing, dask, data-partitioning

I have a very large DataFrame, that I partition based on values in one column "A" using the dask.DataFrame.set_index() method. Such N partitions are still too large to fit into memory when mapping a function "f()" on the dask DataFrame dd.
I would like to further split/partition each of these N partitions in, say, m smaller DataFrames (can be of equal size, or not). This should allow me to dd.map_partitions(f) in an optimal way, given the resources on my cluster.

I tried using the repartition() method on the partitioned dd, but I am either stuck with the N partitions, or ending up with 10 partitions with mixed values of A (which isn't compatible with how my function f works).
One idea would be to dd.map_partitions(repartition, 10) to apply repartition on each df within dd, but that seems quite convoluted.
Any (better) suggestions? Thanks!
p.s.: I am on my phone and can't easily paste a template case, will do later if needed.

Comment: How did you partitioned the DataFrame in the first place if the partitions are too big? Also, if you don't need all the rows with the same "A" value in a single partition, couldn't you adapt f() or create another function to first group the records with the same value in each partition before applying f()?